# How to execute sql file from batch file and display output to screen

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I have (test.batch) a batch file that calls (gett.sql) sql file and executes it.

The problem is how to display the output of sql file on the screen to user.

test.batch file:

```
@echo off
set mypath=%cd%
@ECHO Counter...
set user_name=hr
set password=hr
set net_service_name=ORCL
echo exit | sqlplus -s %user_name%/%password%@%net_service_name% @%mypath%\gett.sql
pause
```

gett.sql file:

```sql
SET ECHO ON
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Message# '||i);
  END LOOP;
END;

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 4):

You did everything right (OK, *almost* everything):

```
M:\a1_maknuto>@test
Counter...

Message# 1
Message# 2
Message# 3
Message# 4
Message# 5

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Press any key to continue . . .

M:\a1_maknuto>
```

What you miss, is a slash that terminates PL/SQL block in `gett.sql` script; also, don't forget to enable output by `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`:

```
SET ECHO ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON       --> this
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Message# '||i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/                         --> this
PAUSE
```

Comment: thanks, it works great , however i got 'Input truncated to n characters'  and found I must insert new line at the end of sql file

Comment: You're welcome. If you had to fix *truncated input* and managed to do that - good for you! I'm glad you made it.